# Liberty Profile - Controlling verbosity of Messages.log

Tags: websphere, ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty

I'm using websphere liberty profile v8.5 and worklight 6.2.

How do we control the verbosity of messages.log file?

According to the [documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/rwlp_logging.html?lang=en), there is a flag for logging level, the 'consoleLogLevel'. However,

> This filter controls the granularity of messages that go to the
>   console.log file. The valid values are INFO, AUDIT, WARNING, ERROR,
>   and OFF. By default, the level is AUDIT.

console.log != messages.log

Since messages.log is spamming like crazy, is there a way to reduce this verbosity that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what kind of messages you see in that log, but you could try to reduce amount of information setting it for example to warning:

```
<logging traceSpecification="*=warning"/>
```

you have also other levels on the page you are referring to.

Comment: Thanks! It worked! I was seeing lots of worklight adapter calls with its payloads. I didn't try that flag before because I though it had only effect on the trace.log file.

Comment: It does vary: there are some messages going to messages.log from Liberty that can not be disabled (we do this for serviceability reasons-- we try to keep that runtime information at a reasonable level, but if something does go wrong, we don't want to have to reproduce the problem to at least get an idea of what's going on with the server).

You can also use SystemOut=off and SystemErr=off to disable those if the output is chatty.